# I've been trying to enlarge the logo of our site when viewed on desktop but no code seems to work. I've tried different versions of this but failed

Tags: css, image, media-queries, responsive

```
@media (max-width: 150px) {
.logo .standard-logo {
height: 80px;
```

}
}

Link - [Website](https://www.vision-tech.in/)

I'm not sure what to adjust further, Will appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@media (max-width: 150px)` means that your rule will apply only when the browser window is 150px wide or less. Also, setting height of the logo will distort it, because its width is limited.
I would suggest something like:

```css
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  #header .logo {
    max-width: 180px;
  }
}
```

You can tweak both the media query and the logo width.